# Ho to set hadoop configuration values from pyspark after 2019?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844631/how-to-set-hadoop-configuration-values-from-pyspark) question:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('my.mapreduce.setting', 'someVal')
```

stopped working due to removal of `_jsc` attribute as pointed out by a comment to that answer from 2019.

> How does one set hadoop configuration from pyspark in versions after `_jsc` attribute was removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [As documented](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) (and seen [in code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L498)) any config item in Spark Config prefixed with `spark.hadoop` is copied over to Hadoop Config without the prefix. So to set `my.mapreduce.setting` in Hadoop conf, set `spark.hadoop.my.mapreduce.setting` in Spark conf.

> The better choice is to use spark hadoop properties in the form of spark.hadoop.*, and use spark hive properties in the form of spark.hive.*. For example, adding configuration “spark.hadoop.abc.def=xyz” represents adding hadoop property “abc.def=xyz”, and adding configuration “spark.hive.abc=xyz” represents adding hive property “hive.abc=xyz”. They can be considered as same as normal spark properties...

2. To set spark config `name` to `value`.

```python
# python
spark.conf.set(<name>, <value>)
```

```scala
// scala
spark.conf.set(<name>, <value>)
```

```R
# R
library(SparkR)
sparkR.session()
sparkR.session(sparkConfig = list(name = "<value>"))
```

```SQL
-- SQL
SET <name> = <value>;
```

Command line with `spark-submit` or `pyspark` or `spark-shell`:

```
--conf "name=value"
```

3. Precedence. [As documented](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).

> Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file.

---

Some links:

- [Customize SparkContext using sparkConf.set(..) when using spark-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397731/customize-sparkcontext-using-sparkconf-set-when-using-spark-shell)
- [How to use custom spark-defaults.conf settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975475/how-to-use-custom-spark-defaults-conf-settings)